# Is there a way to use text-to-speech directly in bb10

Tags: text-to-speech, blackberry-10

I want to generate some text from my bb10 app to give audio feedback to the user.
(But the screenreader like in the accessibility feature is not sufficient)

Has anybody already successfully got text-to-speech implemented?

Comment: There are countless open source projects that do this on PC platforms. You may have your best luck in fitting them to your needs.

Comment: Any library you would recommend? It should have C or C++ interface and must work offline (no server based solution) and it should not occupy too much memory.

Comment: I provided it as an answer for you. If you manage to get it working on BB10 you should put the new source on the internet somewhere. I can't see it being as simple as hitting compile.

Answer (score 0):

There are countless open source projects that do this on PC platforms. You may have your best luck in fitting them to your needs. –  Josh C

Any library you would recommend? It should have C or C++ interface and must work offline (no server based solution) and it should not occupy too much memory. –  thowa

I had to check to make sure it was written in C++ which it is. It is called ESpeak. I heard about it nearly 7 years ago when I was looking for a speech synthesizer that was powerful/robust enough to sound like a human. I believe it was ESpeak, and back then it was a complicated task to get it to spew out realistic sounding speech.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/espeak/files/

This one looks promising as well; however it is written in java.
http://mary.dfki.de/Download/openmary-open-source-emotional-text-to-speech-synthesis-system-released

Found here https://github.com/marytts/marytts